# Multiple Tables or Field With XML Data Type?

Tags: database-design, data-structures

I’m looking for a little advice on database/model  design. I’m setting up a quote system and was wondering how to design the line items table(s) as there are multiple ways of specifying a single `LineItem`;

- **Freeform:** Just enter description and
  total
- **Price List Lookup:** Select an
  item and a qty from a price list
- **Service by Time:** Select a cost centre
  and number of hours
- **Bought Out Goods:**
  Select best price and add mark-up
- **etc.**

I have a `Quote` table that holds the general data (Quote number, client, user date created/modified etc.), the `Quote` can have many `QuoteSection`, `QuoteSection` can have many `LineItem`. 
I can see two (reasonable?) options at the moment

1. Have a table in the database for
   each of the different line item
   options `LineItemFreeform`,
   `LineItemPriceList`, `LineItemService` 
   etc.
2. Have a generic LineItem table with
   an XML Data field, each LineItem
   type I add has a different XML
   schema

Which of the two (if either!) is the better/most flexible option and are there any other suggestions for modelling this type of data?

Comment: OK, after some more investigation it looks like storing XML may be adding too much complexity for the gains of flexibility.
Would still love to hear any other suggestions how to model this setup. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot to go on there, but I'd think about a "line item" supertype, and subtypes for each kind of line item.

I didn't read it closely, but this looks like a fairly decent description of [supertype/subtype modeling](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/sql-by-design-supertypes-and-subtypes).